# Volume of a torus using three integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When trying to calculate the volume of a torus using triple integrals, the integral used to calculate the volume is $\iiint f(z, r, \theta) r dz dr d\theta$. In all the derivations, it is assumed that $f(z,r,\theta)=1$. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are computing volume. The volume of a region is equal to the integral of $1$ over that region. On the other hand, if you were calculating mass, you would replace $1$ with the density function.

Here is the analogy to the single integral: If you integrate $1$ from $a$ to $b$, you get the length of the segment $ab$.  If you integrate another positive function $f$ from $a$ to $b$, you get the mass of the segment $ab$ whose density at $x$ is $f(x)$. This is equal to the area under the graph of $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$ (but don't think of it this way, because in the case of the triple integral, the graph of $f$ lives in $\mathbb R^4$ and is hard to visualize).